# Conditional counting of XML blocks

Tags: xml, xslt, counter

I have an XML file with the following format:

```
<block>
 <name> blocky </name>
 <time1> 20 </time1>
 <time2> 17 </time2>
</block>
<block>
 <name> rocky </name>
 <time1> 3 </time1>
 <time2> 5 </time2>
</block>
...
```

For this matter, I'll define 'diff' of a block to be the value of time1 div the value of time2.

What I need to do, is to calculate the number of blocks that has diff > 10%, and also find a block with a maximum diff and print it's name.

How can this be done using XSLT? I can't update variables so I can't use a counter, nor a maximum value.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I guess a possible solution would be to use a script to modify the XML.. Yet can this be done with XSLT?

Comment: I have posted a solution but I am not sure whether the 100% is the maximum diff value found in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that all the blocks are children of a <blocks> element.

A solution for your problem would be:

```
<xsl:template match="blocks">
    <!-- Count number of blocks with diff greater than a number, in this case 10,
         because I do not know which is the maximum value (100%) that you can
         obtain with your specific data -->
    <xsl:value-of select="count(block[number(time1) div number(time2) >= 10])" />
    <!-- Find a block with maximum diff and print its name -->
    <xsl:for-each select="block">
        <xsl:sort select="number(time1) div number(time2)" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```